# PhaserJS: How to pause P2 physics on collision, accurately

Tags: phaser-framework

Taking this as an example

```
mySprite.body.onBeginContact.add(() =>
{
  if(collisions++ % 3 === 0)
  {
    physics.p2.pause();
    setTimeout(() => physics.p2.resume(), 500);
  }
});
```

when `pause()` is called the sprite is not always touching the collision object, worsened at higher velocity.

Is there a way, other than moving the sprite back against the colliding body to pause the sprite at the exact collision point?

Is it better to use a different means of pausing the sprite?

Comment: I do not understand well. What you want is that if a sprite A collides with the sprite B then the sprite A must "stop" at the collision point?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to identify the best approach to having the sprite stop as close to the collision point as possible, obviously framerate and game timer is coming into play, when the sprite/physics is paused it is sometimes up to ~30 pixels away.

Comment: Instead of stopping physics you can use **sprite body.enable = false** and inclusive **sprite.body.static = true**